# How to store Personal Access Token securely on shared machine

Tags: account-security, github

We have a shared machine in the office, used for demo'ing our product.
I want to be able to fetch the latest code from Github.
We have 2FA enabled, so I can't use my login password for https operations.
I can use a [Personal Access Token as the password](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line).

What is the best way to store this Personal Access Token on the shared machine, so that
A) I can access it, but no one else can.
B) It's easy to get into the clipboard so that I can paste it into the password prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Use a password manager.

> A) I can access it, but no one else can.

This is quite tricky on a shared machine. Using a password manager does ensure nobody will be able to access the *stored* token as it will be encrypted, but malware may still be able to keylog your password manager's master password when you enter it. But in the case of malware, the token can already be stolen when you copy it to clipboard. So, to minimize possible damage, make sure the scope of the token is limited to only those permissions that you need while giving the demo